# SELECT * INTO FAILS

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UTS_USERCLIENT_MAPPING_USER_LIST]
(
    [MAPPING_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [USER_ID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [USER_EMAIL_ID] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [USER_CREATED_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [USER_IS_ACTIVE] [bit] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_UTS_USERCLIENT_MAPPING_USER_LIST] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MAPPING_ID] ASC)
       WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
             IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
             ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

In stored procedure I have this code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROC_UTS_USER_CLIENTMAPPING_LIST_SET] 
    (@RETURN_CODE INT OUTPUT,
     @RETURN_MESSAGE NVARCHAR(512) OUTPUT,
     @XML_USER_LIST xml)
AS
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY x.value('USERNAME[1]','nvarchar(50)')) AS MAPPING_ID,
        x.value('USERNAME[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as USER_ID,
        x.value('EMAILID[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as USER_EMAIL_ID,
        x.value('CREATEDDATE[1]', 'datetime') as USER_CREATED_DATE,
        x.value('ISACTIVE[1]', 'bit') as USER_IS_ACTIVE 
    INTO #tempXML
    FROM @XML_USER_LIST.nodes('/DocumentElement/dtLstUsers') AS TEMPTABLE(x)

    SELECT * 
    INTO UTS_USERCLIENT_MAPPING_USER_LIST 
    FROM #tempXML
END TRY
```

My problem is that above stored procedure is not inserting data into `UTS_USERCLIENT_MAPPING_USER_LIST` from `#tempXML` table.

I have ensured that `#tempXML` table contains values.

[image]

Comment: What error are you getting - or when you say the stored procedure is not inserting the data, what happens?

Comment: It appears you are trying to update an identity field (MAPPING_ID).   You probably need to adjust IDENTITY_INSERT

Comment: table already exists, duplicate values on PK - see my answer below for a list of problems why your stored procedure is not working

Answer (score 3):

There are a few flaws in your query:

1 - you are trying to insert an IDENTITY value without setting IDENTITY_INSERT ON before inserting into your table, and then set it to OFF

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT UTS_USERCLIENT_MAPPING_USER_LIST ON
```

2 - SELECT * INTO table will assume the table doesn't exist and will try to create it there, will fail -> need to use INSERT INTO SELECT

```
INSERT INTO UTS_USERCLIENT_MAPPING_USER_LIST (cols)
SELECT cols
FROM  #temp
```

3 - you are calculating the MAPPING_ID with ROW_NUMBER function which will start from 1 to n (where n is number of nodes you have in xml)every time, but your table has a PRIMARY KEY on MAPPING_ID column which implies is UNIQUE so 2nd time you want to insert MAPPING_ID 1, it will fail.

4 - If you have a CATCH block which is empty, it will hide your errors

Now, the solution without really understanding your needs regarding MAPPING_ID column, is to change the insert statement there to:

```
INSERT INTO UTS_USERCLIENT_MAPPING_USER_LIST ([USER_ID], [USER_EMAIL_ID], [USER_CREATED_DATE], [USER_IS_ACTIVE])
SELECT  [USER_ID], [USER_EMAIL_ID], [USER_CREATED_DATE], [USER_IS_ACTIVE]
FROM    #tempXML
```

OR if you have a valid MAPPING_ID found from xml somehow:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT UTS_USERCLIENT_MAPPING_USER_LIST ON

INSERT INTO UTS_USERCLIENT_MAPPING_USER_LIST ([MAPPING_ID], [USER_ID], [USER_EMAIL_ID], [USER_CREATED_DATE], [USER_IS_ACTIVE])
SELECT  [MAPPING_ID], [USER_ID], [USER_EMAIL_ID], [USER_CREATED_DATE], [USER_IS_ACTIVE]
FROM    #tempXML

SET IDENTITY_INSERT UTS_USERCLIENT_MAPPING_USER_LIST OFF
```

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding you need to mentioned all the column name apart from `Mapping_ID`. see below code

```
INSERT INTO UTS_USERCLIENT_MAPPING_USER_LIST (
        USER_ID,
        USER_EMAIL_ID,
        USER_CREATED_DATE,
        USER_IS_ACTIVE)
select  USER_ID,
        USER_EMAIL_ID,
        USER_CREATED_DATE,
        USER_IS_ACTIVE
 from #tempXML
```

Comment: above logic will work, where drop statement not required

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to turn on IDENTITY_INSERT as Sparky has suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Also a possible solution is that you aren't using IDENTITY column at all - in case it's not needed. (In case this table is getting the data only from this store procedure there is no need to use IDENTITY column):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UTS_USERCLIENT_MAPPING_USER_LIST](
    [MAPPING_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [USER_ID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [USER_EMAIL_ID] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [USER_CREATED_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [USER_IS_ACTIVE] [bit] NULL,

CONSTRAINT [PK_UTS_USERCLIENT_MAPPING_USER_LIST] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MAPPING_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 1):

Real problem was,

`SELECT * INTO` always creates new table.

So I needed to drop the existing table before its creation.

When I :

```
DROP TABLE UTS_USERCLIENT_MAPPING_USER_LIST 

 SELECT * 
    INTO UTS_USERCLIENT_MAPPING_USER_LIST 
    FROM #tempXML
```

Then it worked.

Thank You.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem, dont forget to mak the answer that helped you finding the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just skip the temporary table altogether?

```
-- TRUNCATE TABLE HERE, IF NEED BE

INSERT INTO UTS_USERCLIENT_MAPPING_USER_LIST (<ColumnList>)
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY x.value('USERNAME[1]','nvarchar(50)')) AS MAPPING_ID,
    x.value('USERNAME[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as USER_ID,
    x.value('EMAILID[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as USER_EMAIL_ID,
    x.value('CREATEDDATE[1]', 'datetime') as USER_CREATED_DATE,
    x.value('ISACTIVE[1]', 'bit') as USER_IS_ACTIVE 
FROM @XML_USER_LIST.nodes('/DocumentElement/dtLstUsers') AS TEMPTABLE(x)
```